# Problem of Class not found on Laravel for a form

Tags: php, laravel, class, crud

I tried to follow this tutorial to make a work on Laravel : https://vegibit.com/how-to-set-up-form-submission-in-laravel/ but I got a strange bug and I can't found a way to fix it, I wanted to make a form to insert something in my database and show it in another page (the showing is right, it's just the form page that get this problem) here is a screenshot : [image]

Code :

```
namespace Doreas\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Demand;
class DemandeController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $demande = Demand::all();
        return view('demande.index', ['demande' => $demande]);
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        $demande = Demande::find($id);
        return view('demande.show', ['demande' => $demande]);
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return 'it works';
    }
}
```

I don't understand where the problem of Demand come from

```
<?php

namespace App\Doreas;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Demand extends Model
{
    public function scopeTest($query)
    {
        return $query->where('title', '=', 'test');
    }
}
```

Where I declare the class

Comment: please copy paste your code in the question, the screenshot with the code is not the best way to get helped

Comment: also can you include the code of the file where the class `Demand` is declared ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have imported the class `Demand` using `use App\Demand;`

However its namespace is actually `App\Doreas` so you should do `use App\Doreas\Demand;`

Comment: Sadly the problem still the same, it still say `"Class 'App\Demand' not found"` even with `namespace App\Doreas\Demand;` or `namespace Doreas\Demand;`

Comment: @JorgeSalomon I didn't mean to change the namespace of the class, but the **import**. So in the same file where `DemandeController` is, change `use App\Demand;` to `use App\Doreas\Demand;`.

Comment: I change to `Class 'Doreas\Demand' not found` since with App it didn' work, now I got another error 

`SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'laravel_app.demands' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `demands`)` but it mean that this problem is fixed :D

Comment: this is another kind of issue :) it looks like your DB does not have the table `laravel_app.demands`